# Python Script to populate auth_user failing default value errors

Tags: python, django

So this is my first project with Django.  As a result, I seem to learn new things about how it handles models every day.  Because of this, my database is changing every day.  Each time I want to update my database, I need to drop it, create it, run syncdb, and then populate it with user data.  I was hoping to automate this process with a Python script to save me the hassle of constantly recreating my database.

When I try to run an INSERT command, MySQL is telling me that the column first_name does not have a default value.  I took a quick look at the source (https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py), and the class User definitely defines a default value for the first_name column, as well as many others.  Does anyone now why I am getting this error?

Here is the relevant part of the script:

```
import MySQLdb, os
from django.core.management import call_command

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "DatingWebsite.settings"

db = MySQLdb.connect(user = "project", passwd = "project")
c = db.cursor()

try:
    c.execute("DROP DATABASE projectdb;")
except:
    pass
finally:
    c.execute("CREATE DATABASE projectdb;")
call_command('syncdb', interactive=False)
c.execute("USE projectdb;")

c.executemany("""INSERT INTO auth_user (id, username, email, password)
VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)""",
[
(1, 'bob', 'bob@gmail.com', 'pbkdf2_sha256$10000$A3ww6NUZ8TmS$5UA2sXCMS6x7uIGKe20hDckmisBY/rGUK7aye/tMUIw='),
] )
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be better of using [django south](http://south.aeracode.org/) so that you don't have to recreate your DB every time.

However, if you want to do recreate the DB, you can try using [fixtures to populate data DB](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/).

Answer (score 1):

Neither the source code nor the table in mysql indicates any default non-null value for `first_name` or `last_name` which makes sense. Perhaps you might want to check again?

```
mysql> desc auth_user;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username     | varchar(30)  | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| first_name   | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_name    | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email        | varchar(75)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password     | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_staff     | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_active    | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_superuser | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_login   | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date_joined  | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: I did some research. Evidently, Django implements default values at a layer of abstraction above the database. Even though the DB says default is NULL, Django inserts a default value of its own.